# How to segment image with a set of points, assign each pixel to the nearest point?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I try to implement a method to segment image with seed points, and assign each pixel to nearest point.

for example, if the pixel close to 1, then set to 1.

input:

```
0 0 0 0 0 3 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

output:

```
1 1 1 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 2 3 3
1 1 1 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

current the method take too long time and calculate (width * height * numPoints) times, is there any algorithm can be faster?

---

7 seconds to process 5 9478 * 1868 images, numPoints = 8

```
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    byte index = 0;
                    double distance = double.MaxValue;
                    for (int m = 0; m < elements.Count; m++)
                    {
                        CircleROI circle = roiResized[m];
                        double currentDistance = Math.Abs(i - circle.Center.Y) +
                            Math.Abs(j - circle.Center.X);
                        if (currentDistance < distance)
                        {
                            distance = currentDistance;
                            index = (byte)m;
                        }
                    }

                    *data++ = index;
                }
            }
```

Comment: how man `numPoints`are we talking about? For small number I assume that any data-structure overhead will be worse than the "numPoints"-factor. Maybe  if you post your code we can find other possible optimizations.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I disagree. `width * height * numPoints` means quadratic time if `numPoints` is close to proportional to `width * height`. A method that takes linear time by using an efficient data structure can easily be much, much faster.

Comment: @Stef: That was exactly my question if numPoints is quite small (or eve bounded by a 'small' value)  the overhead of e.g a queue might produce more overhead than the numPoints factor. if it is unbounded or of similar size as width or height of ause your answer would be faster because it's O(width * height) instead of O(width * height * numPoints).

Comment: I hope you are not calculating the **sqrt** to calulate and compare the distances. (That would be quite costly an useless)

Comment: @MrSmith42 numPoints are small, currently power without sqrt takes 9 seconds, simple add taks 7 seconds

Comment: I would try profiling to determine if accessing the  `circle.Center.Y`  `circle.Center.X` or the `Math.Abs(..)` may take a significant amount of time. `distance' can be an integer (profiling can tell if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually a *"Voronoi tessellation"*, so you can use that term to research optimal methods.

You can demonstrate it by taking:

- red for your colour 1 at coordinates (1,1)
- lime green for your colour 2 at coordinates (4,2)
- blue for your colour 3 at coordinates (5,0)

and scaling your input diagram by a factor of 10 to make the result large enough to see. Then draw it with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal:

```
magick -size 60x30 xc: \
   -sparse-color  Voronoi '10,10 red  40,20 lime  50,0 blue' \
   result.png
```

[image]

If you just want to stick to single-channel greyscale, rather than colour, you can use:

```
magick -size 60x30- xc: \
    -sparse-color  Voronoi '10,10 black 40,20 gray 50,0 white' result.png
```

[image]

There is an excellent discussion and tutorial on this and similar techniques by Anthony Thyssen [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#voronoi).

It is related to the *"Delaunay Triangulation"* and, though I have not tested it, I expect the **OpenCV** [implementation](https://learnopencv.com/delaunay-triangulation-and-voronoi-diagram-using-opencv-c-python/) will be extremely fast.

Answer (score 5):

You can make your program work in time proportional to the number of pixels.

Maintain a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) of the pixels you're currently "working on".

Initialise this queue so that it contains all the pixels that are initially non-zero.

Then loop while the queue is not empty:

- Pop a pixel (x, y) from the queue;
- Colour every zero neighbour of (x, y) in the same colour as (x, y);
- Add every pixel that you have coloured to the queue.